# is there a way to simulate calls that are send to console from right-click mouse menu?

Tags: c++, winapi, console

When right clicking on windows console a small menu shows up with commands select, select all, find etc.

My question is there a way to do it from the program itself, for example at the end put command to select all text in console, just as user would do it with his mouse ?

Comment: Well using sendkeys and teh hotkey do e.g. Ctrl A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if it is the active window, you can use SendInput to mimic a keyboard or mouse action. 
Refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If it is not the active window, first you will have to get the console window handle and then post mouse/keyboard messages. Now to get the console window handle you have two methods.

---

Method - 1
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683175(VS.85).aspx

Method - 2

1. GetConsoleTitle() and save it in a variable.
2. Form a unique title so that you can identify the window using FindWindow
3. Use SetConsoleTitle() to set the newly formed title.
4. Use FindWindow(NULL, newly_formed_title) to get the window handle.
5. Call SetConsoleTitle() again to set the old title you saved in the beginning.

In step 4 you have the console window handle.

---

Once you have the console window handle you can use various mouse/keyboard message to simulate the action.